# Regex match all email except email of domain something.com

Tags: regex

I'm using Vbscript/Classic Asp/Vb6

I want to match all email have domain at least .com except something.com , i try to using the follow expression but isn't working

> @(?!something).com$

Comment: Too bad my email `example@centrum.cz` no longer counts as a valid email address :-(

Comment: Yeah i forgot after (?!something) must have .+

Comment: @JanDvorak Yeah, requiring `.com` after an email address is odd...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to specify the *allowed* domains. Try this:

```
@(?!something\.com)([A-Za-z0-9]+\.com)$
```

You can add more characters than A-Z, a-z and 0-9 if you want.
Also, you should escape a dot inside a regex, because the dot is a special character (it matches each character).

Comment: This will also disallow `somethingelse.com` -- you want to make the negative lookahead completely specific `(?!something.com$)`.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to introduce a positive match too.  What's a matching email domain?
Well, if you don't have control over the domain encoding, it may be punycoded already, but it's more likely that it can contain non-ascii characters.  If that's the case, then in general it's easier to be lenient rather than really trying to express the full complexity of what's a possible domain name.  My recommendation is thus to focus on the structure of the domain rather then the exact characters that are legal; however the right choice depends on your need.

A reasonable simple regex for a `.com` domain might be something like:

```
([^.]+\.)+com$
```

Including the restriction that it must be preceded by `@` and not be `something.com`:

```
@(?!something\.com$)([^.]+\.)+com$
```

Note that the negative lookahead includes the `.com` and terminator symbol `$` to it doesn't falsely reject `somethingelse.com` nor `something.comedy.com`.

A limitation is that this accepts [invalid domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Domain_name_syntax) such as `_.com` or `hmm-.com`, so if you'd prefer to reject such cases (but also internationalised domains), you could write:

```
@(?!something\.com$)(([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]*)?[a-z0-9]\.)+com$
```

This ensures valid characters for all labels, allows more than one label (e.g. "mail" and "google" in `mail.google.com`), and ensures no label may start or end with a hyphen.

**Edit:** If you want to enforce the 253 character total-length and per-label 63 character length limits as well, you could do something like this:

```
@(?!.{254})(?!something\.com$)(([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]{0,61})?[a-z0-9]\.)+com$
```

**Limitations:** Unfortunately, since VBScript's unicode-foo is weak, the regex for the allowable unicode characters is quite large (lots of character ranges).  Finally, this regex does not take casing into account: neither does DNS, so that should be fine, but remember to run it in case-insensitive mode or to normalize to lower-case before testing.

Honestly, however: I'd not do this. Keep it simple - do you really care if an invalid emails address is entered?  Then verify the email - no amount of syntactic checking will really work.  Some simple, basic checking - like does it have an `@`, a `.` and not end in `something.com` should catch most accidental errors; but unless you *really* need to, don't bother with this detailed approach.

Comment: Might also relax the requirement for the address to end in `.com`, as per your own comment.